# Does Parse Support Abstract PFObjects?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

My question is can you have an abstract class that inherits from PFObject and is then subclassed to create other classes?

Basically is this possible?

AbstractObject : PFObject
ObjectOne : AbstractObject
ObjectTwo : AbstractObject

I tried implementing it but I run into this error:

> Subclasses of subclasses may not have separate +parseClassName
>   definitions...

Therefore is it not possible to have subclasses of subclasses of PFObjects with different Parse Class Names?

If not, what is the solution or best practice?

SOLUTION: (I was making the abstract class conform to PFSubclassing, don't do that :])

UPMListing

```
class UPMListing: PFObject  {

  var title = ""
...
```

UPMOtherListing

```
class UPMOtherListing: UPMListing, PFSubclassing {

  var category: String?

  override class func parseClassName() -> String! {
    return "UPMOtherListing"
  }

 override class func load() {
  self.registerSubclass()
  }
}
```

Full Error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Subclasses of subclasses
>   may not have separate +parseClassName definitions.
>   UPMarketplace.UPMOtherListing should inherit +parseClassName from
>   UPMarketplace.UPMListing.

Comment: I use that model and it works. Could you post relevant portions of code for the abstract class and one of the 2 subclasses? Also is that a compilation or runtime error?

Comment: It is a run-time error, question updated with relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is because you are registering a subclass:

```
override class func load() {
    self.registerSubclass()
}
```

on a class that's inherited from another registered class. As far as I know that is not possible.

So if you're using a single inheritance model, and `UPMListing` is your base (pseudo-abstract) class, I think you should solve the problem by removing the `load` method from `UPMListing`, or otherwise just the `self.registerSubclass()` call if you want to keep that method for other purposes